# Facebook Login API data-scope permission didn't work?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My code as below, and it's will display Facebook login button, and send permission request for "public_profile, user_groups, publish_actions".

but after user logined, always only has "public_profile", other's setting are missing.
May I know, are there anything I missing?

HTML Code

```
<div class="fb-login-button
    align-right"
    data-max-rows="1"
    data-size="medium"
    data-show-faces="false"
    onlogin="MyFBLogin()"
    data-auto-logout-link="false"
    data-scope="public_profile, user_groups"></div>
```

Javascript Code

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });

    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/all.js', function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxxxxx',
            xfbml: true,  // parse XFBML
            version: 'v2.0'
        });
        $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

});
function MyFBLogin(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //Logined
          }
          else {
            //Not logined
          }
        });
}
```

PS: the permission setting is work when I using my app develop account, but other's account didn't work.

Comment: You need to submit the permissions for review before you can ask people other than yourself.

Comment: Yes, on the facebook login auth page, already missing the reset permission except "public_profile".

Comment: If that was a reply to me I don't know what you mean

Comment: Hi @WizKid, when I press the facebook login button on the page,it prompt login page, show the needed permission on the page, but it show "your public profile." only. so I can't get user's attend group's information.
That is my problem.

Comment: And that is what I answered. You need to submit user_groups for review. When it been approved you can use it. You should also read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_groups to see what is required for you to get it approved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app asks for more than than "public_profile", "email" and "user_friends" permissions it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers.

While facebook accept your review submit, only de developers of the app can do all the actions on the app flow.

[Documentation for review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)

Comment: is this still true if your app is in development mode?